# Rank days of the month that occur most

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-dates

I would like to know which days of the month customers have historically paid on the most. I would like to create a report that has days 1,2,3,4...31 all with a count next to each day for how many times it occurs in our date column. I would also like to do the same with the days of the week if possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(DAY(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A1:A))), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  group by Col1 
  label count(Col1)''", 0))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({ROW(A1:A31), IFERROR(VLOOKUP(ROW(A1:A31), 
 QUERY(DAY(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A1:A))), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  group by Col1 
  label count(Col1)''", 0), 2, 0), 0)})
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({{"Mon";"Tue";"Wed";"Thu";"Fri";"Sat";"Sun"}, 
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP({"Mon";"Tue";"Wed";"Thu";"Fri";"Sat";"Sun"}, 
 QUERY(TEXT(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A1:A)), "ddd"), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  group by Col1 
  label count(Col1)''", 0), 2, 0), 0)})
```

[image: 0]

---

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K19Bt3Eis2lb8DoytkSgBT0OkW15H361rbiiHzgsArk/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Thanks a million. That works a treat!